# Ruby on Rails server connection error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in ruby on rails. And trying to connect with the mysql server. I tried connecting with wamp but didn't work. Now what I did I just copied the libmsql.dll file to my ruby bin directory. But still I can't connect with the server. Here's is the error message. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
C:\row>cd dev  
C:\row\dev>dir  
Volume in drive C has no label.  
Volume Serial Number is F223-E79C   
Directory of C:\row\dev  
09/27/2016  04:02 AM    <DIR>          . 
09/27/2016  04:02 AM    <DIR>          .. 
09/27/2016  04:03 AM    <DIR>          mysql_test                
0 File(s)              
0 bytes                
3 Dir(s)  
37,122,785,280 bytes free  
C:\row\dev>cd mysql_test  
C:\row\dev\mysql_test>ruby test.rb 
C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/clien t.rb:87:in `connect': Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (Mysq l2::Error)         
 from C:/row/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4-x86-mingw32/lib /mysql2/client.rb:87:in `initialize'         
 from test.rb:3:in `new'         
 from test.rb:3:in `<main>'  
C:\row\dev\mysql_test>
```

Comment: post the contents of the test.rb file

Comment: Is your server running? Is it accepting connections?

Comment: The default port for WAMP is `localhost:3306`

Comment: telnet localhost 3306

Comment: Hi, here's the content of my test.rb file. require 'mysql2'

client = Mysql2::Client.new(host: 'localhost', username: 'root', password: 'password1')

sql = 'select NOW() as timestamp'

result = client.query(sql)

result.each do |row|
  puts row['timestamp']
end

Answer (score 0):

To connect the mysql DB into rails you have to make some of the changes to the configuration file `config/database.yml`.

You have to install the gem and then connect to mysql DB.

```
production: 
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8 
database: example 
pool: 10 
username: example 
password: secure 
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 
reconnect: true
```

In addition to that you have to following changes

1. Add `gem 'mysql2'` in your Gemfile

and run `bundle install`.

**Reference:** Here is a very clear explanation of how to connect mysql DB into our rails app.

https://kyokasuigetsu25.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/how-to-configure-rails-to-connect-to-mysql-database/

Comment: Thanks a lot! But, I have the config.yml file but not the config/database.yml file. Let me show you which tutorial I have been following so you can have the idea. I have followed pt 1-3 of his tutorials and now I am lost! :/ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0X7SUfF928